# Is there any indoor plant to help with mold in the room?

Tags: mold

The house I live sits on the rock and I guess there would some problem with isolation and maybe some other issue as well. I have to clean the room time to time with vinegar.

Is there any indoor plant that would help me with mold in the room?

Comment: Questions about plants are better suited for the gardening site. Migrating.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Mold loves moisture, and plants typically like moisture too, so I don't think any plant is going to help control mold. If you introduced 20 plants, you'd also be introducing a lot of moist soil which would further increase the humidity. The best way to control mold is to keep everything dry.

Answer (score 4):

As Steven points out about plants and moister, your best thing to do is get more ventilation in your house.  You could also use an Air Purifier with a HEPA filter to reduce the mold spores floating around.